# jQuery get link id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I'm trying to get the id-attribute of a dynamic generated table. So if I click on the first link I want to get "editEmploee-4".

```
<table id="example" class="table span12 table-bordered table-hover">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Firstname</th>
         <th>Lastname</th>
         <th>Edit</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Person 1</td>
         <td>Name Person 1</td>
         <td><a href="#" class = "editDialog" id="editEmployee-4"><img src="img/edit.png" height="20" /></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Person 2</td>
         <td>Name Person 2</td>
         <td><a href="#" class = "editDialog" id="editEmployee-5"><img src="img/edit.png" height="20" /></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Person 3</td>
         <td>Name Person 3</td>
         <td><a href="#" class = "editDialog" id="editEmployee-47"><img src="img/edit.png" height="20" /></a></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I already tried this code, but I always get the same id.

```
var data = $( "a[id][class=editDialog]" ).attr('id');
```

Do you have any idea how to get the dynamic generated link id?

Comment: When will you be doing this? In the `onclick` handler?

Answer (score 5):

Event delegation:

```
$(document).on("click", "#example a", function() {
    console.log(this.id); //id of clicked link
});
```

Not sure how much of the table is dynamically generated, but you typically want to use the container element rather than `document`

Answer (score 5):

```
$(".editDialog").click(function(e)
{
  e.preventDefault();
  var myID = $(this).attr("id");
 // do something with myID
})
```

Comment: Why jQuery? why not `this.id`?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon force of habit i guess :)

Comment: Those are bad habits :)

Comment: @tymeJV sure it will. I pray to be dynamic code, to eliminate spelling errors on ids and classes :)

Comment: How do you figure it will work? The handlers are bound at runtime, if this content is added after the handlers won't bind?

Comment: @tymeJV I assumed "dynamic generated table" to be just that - table generated by server-side language. Not ajax/javascript generated, which i think you are refering

Comment: Ahh, yeah, probably :\ details people! :D

Answer (score 2):

You can use `this.id` inside click handler of your anchors:

```
$('.editDialog').click(function() {
    var data = this.id;
});
```

---

but since your table has been generated dynamically, all the events will not be available to this table and the elements inside it, in this case you need to apply event delegation technique in order to attach those events such as click in your case to these newly added elements:

```
$(document.body).on("click", "#example a", function() {
    var data = this.id;
});
```

Actually, it'll be more efficient when you bind the delegated events to the closest static parent instead of `$(document)`.

Answer (score 0):

As we have a class "editDialog" in all the  tags. We can use this in our JQuery or Java Script code:

JQuery::

```
$('.editDialog').bind('click', function(){
alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Java Script::

```
$('.editDialog').bind('click',function(){
var clickedID = this.id;
alert(clickedID);
});
```